# In Excel, is there a function that returns a cell value that is in the same row (different column) as a user specified cell?

Tags: excel

On Sheet1, range A1:B6, I have a table like this one:

```
Code Position
   1 Goalkeeper
   2 Defender
   3 Midfielder
   4 Winger
   5 Forward
```

What I want is to get a code for a certain position when I enter it on another sheet. Is there a function that does this? I tried with DGET() but it kept returning #VALUE! AND #NUM!. So I was forced to use IF(). However, it's not a very pretty solution.

```
=IF(S2=Sheet1!$B2;1;
  IF(S2=Sheet1!$B3,2;
    IF(S2=Sheet1!$B4,3;
      IF(S2=Sheet1!$B5,4;
        IF(S2=Sheet1!$B6,5;)))))
```

Now imagine this with a 25 rows table.

Clarification: S2 is a cell on another sheet in which Position is entered.

Comment: DGET is for use with a database. Formula that you probably want to use is MATCH and INDEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the following in S2

`=MATCH(T2, Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,0)`

You can drag this formula down. It returns the relative position of the specified player's 'Position' in the range i.e. B2:B6 in this case.

e.g. GoalKeeper is first so the formula will return 1.

Comment: Great, thatks. MATCH is the function I needed.